# Vector point std::vector<cv::Point>

Tags: c++, opencv, std, stdvector, cout

I am trying to draw a trajectory on an image and saving these trajectory points as `std::vector<cv::Point> trajectoryPoint`  and I would like to access the data inside.

This a short snippet from my code:

```
cv::line(currentFrame, trajectoryPoint.back(), cv::Point(x, y), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 8);
trajectoryPoint.push_back(Point(x, y));
std::cout << trajectoryPoint.at() << std::endl;
```

Normally, in Matlab it is easy to see the data inside vectors. However, I don't know how to continuously print out the data while drawing in C++ inside `trajectoryPoint`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to wrap a `cv::Mat` around it (which has nice printing ops):

```
std::vector<cv::Point> trajectoryPoint = ...
cv::Mat viz(trajectoryPoint);
std::cout << viz << std::endl;
```

Comment: However, I am having difficulty with real-time visualization of trajectoryPoint

Comment: that's a different question, and you probably need to draw points / lines into an image

Comment: solved that one too, thanks again

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<cv:Points>> data This vector fo vetor for storing points how to convert to matrix format.

Comment: @AMAR, you cant. iterate over the outer vector, and wrap a Mat around the inner ones

Comment: cv::Mat image;
    

    std::vector < std::vector<cv::Point>> vecvec;
    std::vector<cv::Point> vecpnt;
    cv::Point pnt;
    pnt.x = 20;
    pnt.y = 50;
    vecpnt.push_back(pnt);
    vecvec.push_back(vecpnt);
    for (int i = 0; i < vecvec.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vecvec[i].size(); j++) {
            
            image.at<int>(i, j) = vecvec[i][j];
        }
    }                   Is this way to allocate vec of vec point to mat              I tried this one it's not working